# Applescript: do a context menu action

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm sorry I couldn't come up with a better title.
I've made a little applescript service that gets the unix path to a file you selected in the Finder and then stores that path in the clipboard.
The files I use this for are in my Google Drive volume and now I'd like to add an extra feature which is powered by Google Drive File Stream application.

If I right click on a Google Drive file in the finder, I get 3 extra items in the context menu, see attached screenshot.
All I want is my script to run "Copy link to clipboard".

So how do I tell apple script to do so?
I'm sorry for the very trivial question, but I think I lack the right terminology to make a Google search, all I could find was how to add an apple script to a context menu, which I already did.

[image: Google Drive - Finder context menu]

Answer (score 2):

Use `AXShowMenu` to open the context menu. Then send the keystroke "Copy link to clipboard" to select the copy action, and send "Enter" to activate the action.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Finder"
    set selectedFile to value of attribute "AXFocusedUIElement"
    tell selectedFile to perform action "AXShowMenu"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "Copy link to clipboard"
    -- Sends enter
    key code 36
end tell
```

Note that this doesn't work properly when using Finder's icon view. The list view or column view must be used.